# Реализация бинарного дерева (С#) без использования встроенных классов и коллекций

Tags: c#, графы, дерево, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

Метод добавления нового узла не работает.

```
class BinaryTree
    {

        class BinaryNode //узел дерева
        {
            public BinaryTree left { get; set; } //указатели узла
            public BinaryTree right { get; set; }
            public int value; //вставляемое значение

            public BinaryNode(int val)
            {
                value = val; //конструктор заполняет узел значением
                left = null;
                right = null;
            }

         }

        class Tree //создание дерева
        {
            public BinaryNode root; //корень дерева
            public Tree() //конструктор (по умолчанию) создания дерева
            {
                root = null; //при создании корень не определен
            }

            public Tree(int value)
            {
                root = new BinaryNode(value); //если изначально задаём корневое значение
            }

            //нерекурсивное добавление
            public void Add(int value) //узел и его значение
            {
                if (root == null)  //если корня нет
                {
                    root = new BinaryNode(value); //добавляем элемент как корневой
                    return;
                }

                BinaryNode current = root; //текущий равен корневому
                bool added = false;
                //обходим дерево
                do
                {
                    if (value >= current.value)  //идём вправо
                    {
                        if (current.right == null)
                        {
                            current.right = new BinaryNode(value);
                            added = true;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            current = current.right;
                        }

                        }
                    if (value<current.value) //идём влево
                    {
                        if(current.left == null)
                        {
                            current.left = new BinaryNode(value);
                            added = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            current = current.left;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current = current.left;
                    }
                }
                while (!added);
            }
```

Правую часть подсвечивает красным (для правого и левого поддерева).

```
current.right = new BinaryNode(value);
current = current.right;
```

Что здесь может быть не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну и не должно компилироваться, у вас ведь `current.right` — это `BinaryTree`, а присваиваете вы ему `BinaryNode`. У вас `BinaryTree` задумывалось, судя по всему, как фасад для имплементации *всего* дерева, так что ваши `left` и `right` должны быть `BinaryNode`.

Затем, непонятно, зачем вам пустой класс `BinaryTree`. Возможно, вам следует «слить» вместе `Tree` и `BinaryTree`. Получится вот что:

```
public class BinaryTree //создание дерева
{
    public class BinaryNode //узел дерева
    {
        public BinaryNode left { get; set; } //указатели узла
        public BinaryNode right { get; set; }
        public int value; //вставляемое значение

        public BinaryNode(int val)
        {
            value = val; //конструктор заполняет узел значением
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    public BinaryNode root; //корень дерева
    public BinaryTree() //конструктор (по умолчанию) создания дерева
    {
        root = null; //при создании корень не определен
    }

    public BinaryTree(int value)
    {
        root = new BinaryNode(value); //если изначально задаём корневое значение
    }

    //нерекурсивное добавление
    public void Add(int value) //узел и его значение
    {
```

и т. д.

У меня это компилируется, но правильность кода я не проверял.